# Roudcube version 1.4.4 long loading time for email detail

Tags: server, debian, webmail, roundcube, ispconfig

Good evening,
can somebody help me please how to optimize Roundcube mail klient (v1.4.4) for faster loading emails?

✓ Logging in is fast
✓ Show mail's list is too fast
✓ Same php version
✘ loading detail of message takes too long (click to e-mail for loading).

When I log the same e-mail account through Roundcube v1.3.11, it's fast, but version 1.4.4 not. So IMAP is working well.

Had you the same problem?

Thank you for your reply. :)

Comment: Noticed the same thing recently. It used to be very fast.